# Why Last_value need frame_clause to have results like First_Value - Window Function PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

This code show 3 try and why Last_value need frame_clause to have results like First_Value

```
select timestamp, 
last_value(timestamp) over (partition by campaign_id order by timestamp
RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as last_day,
last_value(timestamp) over (partition by campaign_id order by timestamp) as last_day2,
first_value(timestamp) over (partition by campaign_id order by timestamp desc) as last_day3
from t1
```

Frame_clause is

> RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING

Result:

[image]

Comment: I actually don't think you needed to use `RANGE` here and `ROWS` would have generated the same result, as least when using `LAST_VALUE`.

Comment: Plz give a specific example or reference because I've never used `ROWS` yet. @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically all window definitions are supposed to have a `RANGE`.

The custom is that if no `RANGE` is specified, then it is assumed to be `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW'.

With that default `RANGE`, `last_value()` is always `CURRENT ROW`, hence `UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` must be specified to get what you want.

Answer (score 4):

That is because the default frame for window functions with an `ORDER BY` in the window definition defaults to

```
RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
```

That happens to give the first value of the window for `first_value`, but a peer of the the current row for `last_value`.